# How can I parse nested JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I have a new project where I obtain JSON data back from a REST API - I'm trying to parse this data to csv pipe delimited to import to our legacy software
I can't seem to get all the value pairs parsed properly - this is my first exposure to JSON and I've tried so many things but only getting a little right at a time

I have used Python and can get some items that I need but not the whole JSON tree - it comes across as a list and has some dictionaries and lists in it as well
I know my code is incomplete and just looking for someone to point me in the right direction on what tools in python can get the job done

```
import json
import csv

with open('tenants.json') as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)


for rm_access in read_content:
    rm_data = rm_access

print(rm_data)
contacts_data = rm_data['Contacts']
leases_data = rm_data['Leases']
udfs_data = rm_data['UserDefinedValues']

for contacts_access in contacts_data:
    rm_contacts = contacts_access
```

UPDATED:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('tenants.json') as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)

for rm_access in read_content:
    rm_data = rm_access

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 150)

TenantID = []
TenantDisplayID = []
Name = []
FirstName = []
LastName = []
WebMessage = []
Comment = []
RentDueDay = []
RentPeriod = []
FirstContact = []
PropertyID = []
PostingStartDate = []
CreateDate = []
CreateUserID = []
UpdateDate = []
UpdateUserID = []
Contacts = []
for rm_access in read_content:
    rm_data = rm_access

    TenantID.append(rm_data["TenantID"])
    TenantDisplayID.append(rm_data["TenantDisplayID"])
    Name.append(rm_data["Name"])
    FirstName.append(rm_data["FirstName"])
    LastName.append(rm_data["LastName"])
    WebMessage.append(rm_data["WebMessage"])
    Comment.append(rm_data["Comment"])
    RentDueDay.append(rm_data["RentDueDay"])
    RentPeriod.append(rm_data["RentPeriod"])
#    FirstContact.append(rm_data["FirstContact"])
    PropertyID.append(rm_data["PropertyID"])
    PostingStartDate.append(rm_data["PostingStartDate"])
    CreateDate.append(rm_data["CreateDate"])
    CreateUserID.append(rm_data["CreateUserID"])
    UpdateUserID.append(rm_data["UpdateUserID"])
    Contacts.append(rm_data["Contacts"])


df = pd.DataFrame({"TenantID":TenantID,"TenantDisplayID":TenantDisplayID, "Name"
: Name,"FirstName":FirstName, "LastName": LastName,"WebMessage": WebMessage,"Com
ment": Comment, "RentDueDay": RentDueDay, "RentPeriod": RentPeriod, "PropertyID"
: PropertyID, "PostingStartDate": PostingStartDate,"CreateDate": CreateDate, "Cr
eateUserID": CreateUserID,"UpdateUserID": UpdateUserID,"Contacts": Contacts})

print(df)
```

Here is sample of the file

```
[
  {
    "TenantID": 115,
    "TenantDisplayID": 115,
    "Name": "Jane Doe",
    "FirstName": "Jane",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "WebMessage": "",
    "Comment": "",
    "RentDueDay": 1,
    "RentPeriod": "Monthly",
    "FirstContact": "2015-11-01T15:30:00",
    "PropertyID": 17,
    "PostingStartDate": "2010-10-01T00:00:00",
    "CreateDate": "2014-04-16T13:35:37",
    "CreateUserID": 1,
    "UpdateDate": "2017-03-22T11:31:48",
    "UpdateUserID": 1,
    "Contacts": [
      {
        "ContactID": 128,
        "FirstName": "Jane",
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "IsPrimary": true,
        "DateOfBirth": "1975-02-27T00:00:00",
        "FederalTaxID": "111-11-1111",
        "Comment": "",
        "Email": "jane.doe@mail.com",
        "License": "ZZT4532",
        "Vehicle": "BMW 3 Series",
        "IsShowOnBill": true,
        "Employer": "REW",
        "ApplicantType": "Applicant",
        "CreateDate": "2014-04-16T13:35:37",
        "CreateUserID": 1,
        "UpdateDate": "2017-03-22T11:31:48",
        "AnnualIncome": 0.0,
        "UpdateUserID": 1,
        "ParentID": 115,
        "ParentType": "Tenant",
        "PhoneNumbers": [
          {
            "PhoneNumberID": 286,
            "PhoneNumberTypeID": 2,
            "PhoneNumber": "703-555-5610",
            "Extension": "",
            "StrippedPhoneNumber": "7035555610",
            "IsPrimary": true,
            "ParentID": 128,
            "ParentType": "Contact"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "UserDefinedValues": [
      {
        "UserDefinedValueID": 1,
        "UserDefinedFieldID": 4,
        "ParentID": 115,
        "Name": "Emerg Contact Name",
        "Value": "Terry Harper",
        "UpdateDate": "2016-01-22T15:41:53",
        "FieldType": "Text",
        "UpdateUserID": 2,
        "CreateUserID": 2
      },
      {
        "UserDefinedValueID": 174,
        "UserDefinedFieldID": 5,
        "ParentID": 115,
        "Name": "Emerg Contact Phone",
        "Value": "703-555-3568",
        "UpdateDate": "2016-01-22T15:42:03",
        "FieldType": "Text",
        "UpdateUserID": 2,
        "CreateUserID": 2
      }
    ],
    "Leases": [
      {
        "LeaseID": 115,
        "TenantID": 115,
        "UnitID": 181,
        "PropertyID": 17,
        "MoveInDate": "2010-10-01T00:00:00",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "CreateDate": "2014-04-16T13:35:37",
        "UpdateDate": "2017-03-22T11:31:48",
        "CreateUserID": 1,
        "UpdateUserID": 1
      }
    ],
    "Addresses": [
      {
        "AddressID": 286,
        "AddressTypeID": 1,
        "Address": "14393 Montgomery Road Lot #102\r\nCincinnati, OH 45122",
        "Street": "14393 Montgomery Road Lot #102",
        "City": "Cincinnati",
        "State": "OH",
        "PostalCode": "45122",
        "IsPrimary": true,
        "ParentID": 115,
        "ParentType": "Tenant"
      }
    ],
    "OpenReceivables": [],
    "Status": "Current"
  },
```

Not all tenants will have all elements which is also tricky

I need the data from the top where there is TenantID, TenantDisplayID, etc
I also need the data from the Contacts, PhoneNumbers, Leases, etc values
Each line should be static so if it doesn't have certain tags then I'd like a Null or None so it would look like
TentantID|TenantDisplayID|FirstName….etc so each line has same number of fields

Comment: There’s no magic bullet - for each `rm_data` you’re going to have to code extracting each field from `rm_data` and storing it in your output dictionary, and add these to the output list.

Comment: SInce CSV format doesn't support nesting, you're going to have to "flatten" it and map it into rows of identical fields. There a large number of similar questions here...have you looked at any of them? Surely one is similar to what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I've looked at a lot of them- but none have seemed to contain same data structure - haven't found one to loop through all the nesting - hence why I asked my question

Comment: It's not surprising the none of them has _exactly_ the same data-structure. The point is to understand how the problem can be solved generally so you can apply the concept to a similar problem.

Comment: Well I get that - I'm not saying I was looking for the 'exact' same structure - but I wasn't familiar with json until about 4-5 days ago - and how you can have lists and dictionaries within that list and then another list etc - almost all of the examples I've seen and what I've been reading only deal with getting 1 value from 1 place and about 90% of the json I've seen the structures have all been static but unfortunately mine is not - thanks for your insight though - I have been learning it but I'm getting up against a deadline soon and just looking to get pointed in the right direction

Comment: Did you really just post a sample record that contains a full name, address, phone number, license plate number, and Federal tax ID (i.e. social security number) of a random woman in Ohio?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100000)
TenantID = []
TenantDisplayID = []
Name = []
FirstName = []
LastName = []
WebMessage = []
Comment = []
RentDueDay = []
RentPeriod = []
FirstContact = []
PropertyID = []
PostingStartDate = []
CreateDate = []
CreateUserID = []
UpdateDate = []
UpdateUserID = []
Contacts = []
for rm_access in read_content:
    rm_data = rm_access

    print(rm_data)
    TenantID.append(rm_data["TenantID"])
    TenantDisplayID.append(rm_data["TenantDisplayID"])
    Name.append(rm_data["Name"])
    FirstName.append(rm_data["FirstName"])
    LastName.append(rm_data["LastName"])
    WebMessage.append(rm_data["WebMessage"])
    Comment.append(rm_data["Comment"])
    RentDueDay.append(rm_data["RentDueDay"])
    RentPeriod.append(rm_data["RentPeriod"])
    FirstContact.append(rm_data["FirstContact"])
    PropertyID.append(rm_data["PropertyID"])
    PostingStartDate.append(rm_data["PostingStartDate"])
    CreateDate.append(rm_data["CreateDate"])
    CreateUserID.append(rm_data["CreateUserID"])
    UpdateUserID.append(rm_data["UpdateUserID"])
    Contacts.append(rm_data["Contacts"])


df = pd.DataFrame({"TenantID":TenantID,"TenantDisplayID":TenantDisplayID, "Name": Name,
                   "FirstName":FirstName, "LastName": LastName,"WebMessage": WebMessage,
                   "Comment": Comment, "RentDueDay": RentDueDay, "RentPeriod": RentPeriod,
                   "FirstContact": FirstContact, "PropertyID": PropertyID, "PostingStartDate": PostingStartDate,
                   "CreateDate": CreateDate, "CreateUserID": CreateUserID,"UpdateUserID": UpdateUserID,
                   "Contacts": Contacts})

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try - I actually just installed pandas earlier today - at first run I got  FirstContact.append(rm_data["FirstContact"] KeyError: 'FirstContact'  so just to see what would happen I commented out that line and then I got AttributeError: module 'pandas' has not attribute 'DataFrame' ? but I confirmed I have pandas installed and it doesn't complain when I do import pandas as pd -- doing import sys  and sys.path I see  '/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages' and I had no errors when installing pandas - I'm looking more at it now

Comment: sorry had to rename my file - it was called pandas.py oops sorryZZ - when I ran it it returned  Comment    WebMessage  and then columns going down 0 to 4 then .. 180 to 184 and just a series of dots after that

Comment: you can add the following to expand the columns of the dataframe:pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100000).

Comment: Okay I did that - now it shows TenantID  UpdateUserID and WebMessage but those are the only fields showing - the first two columns are numbered down 0 to 184 which is correct - there are 185 records in the json file - all TenantID's look good - just not sure why other columns aren't showing up

Comment: Can you update your post with your most recent code?

Comment: updated it above with how it is now with the commented out field and I removed it from the df variable as well

Answer (score 0):

## The General Problem

The problem with this task (and other similar ones) is not just how to create an algorithm - I am sure you will theoretically be able to solve this with a (not so) nice amount of nested for-loops. The problem is to organise the code in a way that you don't get a headache - i.e. in a way that you can fix bugs easily, that you can write unittests, that you can understand the code easily from reading it (in six months from now) and that you can easily change your code in case you need to do so. 
I do not know anybody who does not make mistakes when wrapping their head around a deeply nested structure. And chasing for bugs in a code which is heavily nested because it mirrors the nested structure of the data, can be quite frustrating.

## The Quick (and most probably: Best) Solution

Rely on packages that are made for your exact usecase, such as

https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects

In case you have a formal definition of the API schema, you could use packages for that. If, for instance, your API has a Swagger schema definition, you cann use `swagger-py` (https://github.com/digium/swagger-py) to get your JSON response into Python objects.

## The Principle Solution: Object Oriented Programming and Recursion

Even if there might be some libraries for your concrete use case, I would like to explain the principle of how to deal with "that kind" of tasks:

A good way to organise code for this kind of problem is using *Object Oriented Programming*. The nesting hassle can be laid out much clearer by making use of the principle of *recursion*. This also makes it easier to chabge the code, in case the JSON schema of your API response changes for any reasons (an update of the API, for instance). In your case I would suggest you create something like the following:

```
class JsonObject:
    """Parent Class for any Object that will be retrieved from the JSON
    and potentially has nested JsonObjects inside.

    This class takes care of parsing the json into python Objects and deals
    with the recursion into the nested structures."""

    primitives = []
    json_objects = {
        # For each class, this dict defines all the "embedded" classes which
        # live directly "under" that class in the nested JSON. It will have the
        # following structure:

        # attribute_name : class

        # In your case the JSON schema does not have any "single" objects
        # in the nesting strcuture, but only lists of nested objects. I
        # still , to demonstrate how you would do it in case, there would be
        # single "embedded"
    }
    json_object_lists = {
        # For each class, this dict defines all the "embedded" subclasses which
        # are provided in a list "under" that class in the nested JSON.
        # It will have the following structure:

        # attribute_name : class
    }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: dict) -> "JsonObject":
        instance = cls()

        for attribute in cls.primitives:
            # Here we just parse all the primitives
            instance.attribute = getattr(d, attribute, None)

        for attribute, klass in cls.json_object_lists.items():
            # Here we parse all lists of embedded JSON Objects
            nested_objects = []
            l = getattr(d, attribute, [])
            for nested_dict in l:
                nested_objects += klass.from_dict(nested_dict)

            setattr(instance, attribute, nested_objects)

        for attribute, klass in cls.json_objects.items():
            # Here we parse all "single" embedded JSON Objects
            setattr(
                instance,
                attribute,
                klass.from_dict(getattr(d, attribute, None)
            )

    def to_csv(self) -> str:
        pass
```

Since you didn't explain how exactly you want to create a csv from the JSON, I didn't implement that method and left this to you. It is also not necessary to explain the overall approach.

Now we have the general Parent class all our specific will inherit from, so that we can apply recursion to our problem. Now we only need to define these concrete structures, according to the JSON schema we want to parse. I got the following from your sample, but you can easily change the things you need to:

```
class Address(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "AddressID",
        "AddressTypeID",
        "Address",
        "Street",
        "City",
        "State",
        "PostalCode",
        "IsPrimary",
        "ParentID",
        "ParentType",
    ]

    json_objects = {}
    json_object_lists = {}


class Lease(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "LeaseID",
        "TenantID",
        "UnitID",
        "PropertyID",
        "MoveInDate",
        "SortOrder",
        "CreateDate",
        "UpdateDate",
        "CreateUserID",
        "UpdateUserID",
    ]

    json_objects = {}
    json_object_lists = {}


class UserDefinedValue(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "UserDefinedValueID",
        "UserDefinedFieldID",
        "ParentID",
        "Name",
        "Value",
        "UpdateDate",
        "FieldType",
        "UpdateUserID",
        "CreateUserID",
    ]

    json_objects = {}
    json_object_lists = {}


class PhoneNumber(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "PhoneNumberID",
        "PhoneNumberTypeID",
        "PhoneNumber",
        "Extension",
        "StrippedPhoneNumber",
        "IsPrimary",
        "ParentID",
        "ParentType",
    ]

    json_objects = {}
    json_object_lists = {}

class Contact(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "ContactID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "MiddleName",
        "IsPrimary",
        "DateOfBirth",
        "FederalTaxID",
        "Comment",
        "Email",
        "License",
        "Vehicle",
        "IsShowOnBill",
        "Employer",
        "ApplicantType",
        "CreateDate",
        "CreateUserID",
        "UpdateDate",
        "AnnualIncome",
        "UpdateUserID",
        "ParentID",
        "ParentType",
    ]

    json_objects = {}
    json_object_lists = {
        "PhoneNumbers": PhoneNumber,
    }


class Tenant(JsonObject):
    primitives = [
        "TenantID",
        "TenantDisplayID",
        "Name",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "WebMessage",
        "Comment",
        "RentDueDay",
        "RentPeriod",
        "FirstContact",
        "PropertyID",
        "PostingStartDate",
        "CreateDate",
        "CreateUserID",
        "UpdateDate",
        "UpdateUserID",
        "OpenReceivables",  # Maybe this is also a nested Object? Not clear from your sample.
        "Status",
    ]

    json_object_lists = {
        "Contacts": Contact,
        "UserDefinedValues": UserDefinedValue,
        "Leases": Lease,
        "Addresses": Address,
    }

    json_objects = {}
```

You might imagine the "beauty" (at least: order) of that approach, which lies in the following: With this structure, we could tackle any level of nesting in the JSON response of your API without additional headache - our code would not deepen its indentation level, because we have separated the nasty nesting into the recursive definition of `JsonObject`s `from_json` method. That is why it is much easier now to identify bugs or apply changes to our code.

To finally parse the JSON now into our Objects, you would do something like the following:

```
import typing
import json


def tenants_from_json(json_string: str) -> typing.Iterable["Tenant"]:
    tenants = [
        Tenant.from_dict(tenant_dict)
        for tenant_dict in json.loads(json_string)
    ]
    return tenants
```

## Important Final Side Note: This is just the basic Principle

My code example is just a very brief introduction into the idea of using objects and recursion to deal with an overwhelming (and nasty) nesting of a structure. The code has some flaws. For instance one should avoid define mutable class variables. And of course the whole code should validate the data it gets from the API. You also might want to add the type of each attribute and represent that correctly in the Python objects (Your sample has integers, datetimes and strings, for instance).

I really only wanted to show you the very principle of Object Oriented Programming here.

I didn't take the time to test my code. So there are probably bugs left. Again, I just wanted to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I appreciate you taking time to thoroughly explain the approach and it certainly makes sense - thanks again - and yes OpenReceivables is another nested entity